# How do I filter Search API results based on imformation stored on a related entity?

Tags: entities, search

I'm working on adding Search Api to my sites. I need to be able to filter content in the search based on data not stored on the nose however. The content Types in Question are Story Pages, which hold the relevant data, and Chapter pages which reference the Stories.

In a normal view I would use a relationship and just do it that way, but the Search View isn't allowing me to set a relationship on filters.

How do I get there from here?

Comment: Are you using drupal core serch api or any contributed module?

Comment: Search API is not a Drupal core module.

Comment: I was asking, whether we are using core search functionality or any custom module. If you are using search api then you need index all related field then only you can add filter in views.

Comment: So I will need to imdex the field_story and everything connected to those nodes a second time then?

Comment: So maybe it's not an issue with Search API. Whenever I try to filter results based on multiple fields that might be part of the same content type, Views outright stops showing all content. Not just content that I've tried to filter out, but everything. I'm not sure why.